# Concatenate files from 011 to 019

Tags: bash

I have the following files

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
ls  | head -15
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| 00.contents.org                       |
| 00.preface.html                       |
| C_Programming_Language_split_011.html |
| C_Programming_Language_split_012.html |
| C_Programming_Language_split_013.html |
| C_Programming_Language_split_014.html |
| C_Programming_Language_split_015.html |
| C_Programming_Language_split_016.html |
| C_Programming_Language_split_017.html |
| C_Programming_Language_split_018.html |
| C_Programming_Language_split_019.html |
| C_Programming_Language_split_020.html |
| C_Programming_Language_split_021.html |
| C_Programming_Language_split_022.html |
| C_Programming_Language_split_023.html |
```

I plan to concatenate from 011 to 019 and tried

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :results output
ls C_Programming_Language_split_0[11-19].html
#+END_SRC
```

It report error:

```
 ls: cannot access 'C_Programming_Language_split_0[11-19].html': No such file or directory
```

How could get it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *brace expansion* in place of `[11-19]`

```
ls C_Programming_Language_split_0{11..19}.html
```

or

```
ls C_Programming_Language_split_{011..019}.html
```

`[11-19]` is a glob expression that matches a single character `1`, or a character from the range from `1` to `1`, or `9` (so either `1` or `9`).